# How do I filter a rust stream by an ascending value?

Tags: rust

How do I write a Rust stream filter that only allows ascending values?  I ask this because I'm not sure how to have a stateful filter in rust.

I'd expect there to be some combination of scan/filter that could be called like this, but I don't know how to compose them

```
futures::stream::iter(vec[1,2,3,2,1,6])
    .filter_stateful(0, |initial_state, new_value| async move {
        if intial_state < new_value {
           *initial_state = new_value
           // only return a new value if changed
           Some(new_value)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable outside the scope of the closure, as long as you don't need to perform any async operations within:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut prev = None;

    let filtered = futures::stream::iter(vec![1,2,3,2,1,6]).filter_map(|current| {
        let result = match prev {
            Some(p) if current <= p => None,
            _ => {
                prev = Some(current);
                // only return a new value if changed
                Some(current)
            },
        };

        std::future::ready(result)
    });

    dbg!(filtered.collect::<Vec<_>>().await);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae695789e24cbdb181f10125f6ca2e32)